# refresh webpage on background tab in firefox or google-chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

I would like to keep logged in to a website that automatically logs me out after 10 minutes of inactivity. Is there any tool to do a "Refresh" on a specific background tab for a webpage in firefox or google-chrome every X minutes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take your pick:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/reloadevery/

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/auto-refresh/

There are probably more, just use the search.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/), its add-on has such functionality.

> LastPass is a password manager that makes web browsing easier and more secure.

[image: LastPass Option]

Answer (score 1):

I just know Avant browser has the auto-refresh feature.
If you like using firefox or chrome, you can use the firefox engine or chrome engine in Avant browser.(It's a tri-core browser)
Maybe there is add-on in firefox can do this, but I rarely use firefox and don't know exactly.